# Android OnClickListener in an ImageView of ListView

Tags: android, listview, onclick, android-imageview

I have a `ListView` in my layout. To display the listing in it, I have used the following code.

```
ListView shopActivityListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.shopActivityListView);
shopActivityListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.shopitem, R.id.text1,trackArr[1]));
```

Here is xml for `shopitem.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:paddingTop="2dip"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:mode="twoLine"> <!-- android:background="@drawable/homebg" -->
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="44dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:lines="1"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/buyBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:paddingTop="3dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="252dip"
            android:layout_alignRight="@android:id/text1"
            android:src="@drawable/btnbuy"/>            
</TwoLineListItem>
```

Now I want to add a `onClickListener` on the `ImageView` of each item. How can I add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement ArrayAdapter and put onclicklistners in GetView. 
Here is a link to custom listview : http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

GetView function is under implemented ArrayAdapter class.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `OnItemClickListener` and set it up for the listView. Make the ImageView clickable in the android xml.

In the method `onItemClick` check for the ImageView id and you should be good to go..